# Install Air Conditioning in the car that does not have air conditioning build in

Tags: honda, ac, accord, installation

Is it good idea for me to install air conditioning in my car if my car does not have air conditioning build in?  Is it worth for me to spend the money to buy and install the air conditioning or it is better for me to buy new car with air conditioning build in instead?

Thank you for answering!

Comment: This is a subjective question. It's more a common sense/personal finance question. Have you ever worked on an AC system? Are you thinking of a conversion with parts from a donor car or an aftermarket AC system? What kind of budget do you have for this project? Could you tell us what kind of vehicle?

Comment: Make, Model, Year?

Comment: Honda Accord 2004. (DX)

Comment: I really dont have budget plan or anything like that.  I just want to know if it is worth it?

Comment: To ask if it is worth it is akin to a shopping question, which is off topic here on this SE. I would advise you to rethink your question in the form of *is it feasible* to install A/C in your car or *what is involved* with installing A/C in your car. Then you can make an informed decision in accordance with your skill level and your finances. We, unfortunately, cannot tell you these things, as @DavidWinslow is suggesting.

Comment: Ok. I see. I apologized for off topic. But please do keep eye of my next question. I have a question about the door lock. It's repair related.

Comment: I recently asked a similar question here, might help you :) [Is it difficult to retrofit Air Conditioning?](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/18068/is-it-difficult-to-retrofit-air-conditioning)